# Where to put accesstoken?

Tags: arcgis

I'm exploring the REST API of ArcGIS and I'm able to generate a accesstoken. But for further requests, for instance `/MapServer/0?f=pjson` I get `499 - Token Required`.

I need to put that token I have in a header, but which one?

The tutorial for obtaining the token describes how to get it, but not what to do with it for rest of the calls.

Comment: This question would be much more on-topic at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: This is more of a developer question than a GIS question and is more appropriate here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting either this header:

`X-Esri-Authorization: Bearer <token>`

Or this header:

`Authorization: Bearer <token>`

Details: https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/windows/about-arcgis-tokens.htm